# Form Helper default values from URL

Tags: cakephp-3.0, formhelper

I have a form with method=GET.

```
echo $this->Form->create(NULL, array('type' => 'get'));
echo $this->Form->input('a');
echo $this->Form->input('b');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

But when calling `formpage/?a=1&b=2` the input fields are not set with those values. Is there a way to pass `$this->request->query` into the form helper to set those defaults at once?

Comment: You should have access to `$this->request` in your view, so you could do something like `echo $this->Form->input('a', ['default' => $this->request->query('a'));` If you have a lot of these, you might instead want to initialize an entity from `$this->request->data` and pass that into `$this->Form->create`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Exactly, I'm looking for the solution to pass a lot of params into the form at once! How do I do that in Form->create???

Comment: `$entity = new Entity($this->request->data); echo $this->Form->create($entity);` would be one way. Not a perfect way, but perhaps enough to get you on the right path. The key takeaway here is the use of the entity to initialize the form; you'll almost certainly want to change the method of creating the entity.